# React router, add # to url

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I uploaded alot of react packages. Some update caused the # to be removed from the url. Works on dev machine but not on production which runs apache. I tried all different kind of rewrite in virtual host but I can't get it to work.

I need to add the `#` again. Must be some option som react router package?

Sorry for not specifying exactly what react packages it is. I updated so many I don't really know which it is. Production is down cause of this so it's an emergency. I promise to clean up the question once it's back up.

Answer (score 0):

react-router-dom has HashRouter component. You can use that.